# List for all team sites for a specific user

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I am looking for the possibility to display all the team sites a user is member of in the my site for the user.Also the possibility for the admin to get the same information about different user.

Is it possible in SharePoint 2010 entreprise edition? if yes could you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you have EnterpriseSearch set up, it already has that information for you, so you can query that with very good performance.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/ff828c3f-9f35-4d71-9870-156625d1f81b

Answer (score 1):

You can use powershell to view list of all sites within a site collection user has access to.

**SCRIPT**

```
`$user = "YOUR DOMAIN\YOUR USER"`
`$site = $gc | Get-SPSite YOURSITECOLLECTIONURL`
`$site | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Get-SPUserEffectivePermissions $user | Out-GridView -Title "Web Permissions for $user"
```

`

The "Get-SPUserEffectivePermissions" commandlet is a custom commandlet that was part of a bigger package hosted by codeplex.com. It is no longer avaliable from the website,

Comment: have a look here -http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sharepoint2010general/thread/73217e48-e024-4ed5-825c-7d850e59b327

Answer (score 1):

Its already been asked i think? here is the code snippit and url :)

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://example/site/")) 
{ 
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) 
    { 
        SPWebCollection webCollection = web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser(); 
    } 
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205050/how-to-retrieve-the-list-of-sharepoint-sites-user-has-access-to-from-a-window